# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, database-performance, sqlperformance

There is a production issue where one of the stored procedures stated taking too much time - on an average it takes 15-20 sec but in one of the day it took more than 100 sec.

It happened last week, Monday and it again repeated this week too - on Tuesday. We checked the load on the DB everything is consistent, there is no high volume on Mondays or Tuesdays.

All other stored procedures on the same DB working as expected. But only this stored procedure which touches few additional tables taking too much time. After re-indexing only it is coming to normal. This stored procedure internally calls few other stored procedures and functions.

What could be wrong?

It cannot be something related to network as impact is only on one stored procedure.

It cannot be something related to DB load or CPU utilization as impact is only on one stored procedure.

There is no scheduled jobs which runs only on Mondays or Tuesdays.

Comment: It sounds like you need more information. I would suggest running a trace using SQL profiler to see if you can identify what is going on when you experience the performance problems.

Comment: Yeah Execution plan will give important information to see what is causing bottleneck. If you share I can help to review.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at activities see what process taking most CPU and use SQL profiler to see how much resources queries takes. Since you are sure that the stored procedure taking too much CPU then you must examine how the queries are executed. 
In query analyzer, enable Show Actual Execution Plan. This is where I will examine how query are executed, whether it is using index or table scan, sort algorithm, etc. It show what function that consumes the most CPU. If it's read query, I will examine the tables and see how internally fragmented is the table and how many pass it takes to retrieve data. If it's write query then I will examine the row/table lock and journal. If you change recovery model from simple to full, write can take considerable amount of time. 
If you had done the execution plan, paste execution the picture with stored procedure here so that I can see what actually slowing down your execution. 
Fix them by changing your SQL query, indexing, query hint and table partitioning.